# Unable to access Controller getter in VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

**Controller Class: TestController.cls**

```
public class TestController {
    private integer num { get; set; }

    public TestController() {
        num = 100;
    }

    /* If I define the getter as below everything works fine
     public integer getNum() {
        return num;
    } */

}
```

**VisualForce Page: TestPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    {!num}
</apex:page>
```

The above throws the following error.

> Unknown property 'TestController.num'

- Create Apex property 'TestController.num'
- Create Apex method 'TestController.getNum'

I am not sure why I have to declare getters again just to use it in VisualForce page. Am I missing anything in `{get; set;}` syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is `private` in order to access your variable this should be public..

```
private integer num { get; set; }
```

Change to

```
public integer num { get; set; }
```

[**Access Modifiers**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm)

> **private**
>
> This is the default, and means that the method or variable is
>   accessible only within the Apex class in which it is defined. If you
>   do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.
>
> **protected**
>
> This means that the method or variable is visible to any inner classes
>   in the defining Apex class, and to the classes that extend the
>   defining Apex class. You can only use this access modifier for
>   instance methods and member variables. Note that it is strictly more
>   permissive than the default (private) setting, just like Java.
>
> **public**
>
> This means the method or variable can be used by any Apex in this
>   application or namespace.
>
> **global**
>
> This means the method or variable can be used by any Apex code that
>   has access to the class, not just the Apex code in the same
>   application. This access modifier should be used for any method that
>   needs to be referenced outside of the application, either in the SOAP
>   API or by other Apex code. If you declare a method or variable as
>   global, you must also declare the class that contains it as global.

[**Apex Properties**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Comment: Will it make the statements **{ get; set; }** after the variable also private ?

Comment: @karthikselva If your variable is `{ get; set; }` with private access modifier. It will not be accessible in VF page.. If it is public then it will be accessible in VF page.

Comment: Cool its working. Thanks I was under the impression getters are always declared public as in Java.

Comment: @karthikselva cool.. You can check the docs for more info

Comment: sure I am getting an message can accept in 1 minute. Thanks for the detailed edit

Answer (score 2):

Apex allows you to use the private, protected, public, and global access modifiers when defining methods and variables.

**private**
This is the default, and means that the method or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it is defined. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.

**protected**
This means that the method or variable is visible to any inner classes in the defining Apex class, and to the classes that extend the defining Apex class. You can only use this access modifier for instance methods and member variables. Note that it is strictly more permissive than the default (private) setting, just like Java.

**public**

This means the method or variable can be used by any Apex in this application or namespace.

So in your case if you want it to accessible in visualforce page. You need to define as **public**

```
public integer num { get; set; }
```

You can read more about access modifier and there behaviour from [Apex Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex5_2.htm)